# Overlay png image with color (php)

Tags: php, image

I have an image like that

[image]

---

And i need to turn in like that

[image]

Also I need to keep transparent edges.

Comment: Create another image and display them accordingly.

Comment: Hmmm.... I need to automate process with php.

Comment: SO what have tried for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer to use `GD` over ImageMagick, you can do it like this:

```
<?php
// Load the PNG image 
$im = imageCreateFromPng("image.png");

// Ensure true colour
imagepalettetotruecolor($im);

// Iterate over all pixels
for ($x = 0; $x < imagesx($im); $x++) {
   for ($y = 0; $y < imagesy($im); $y++) {
      // Get color, and transparency of this pixel
      $col=imagecolorat($im,$x,$y);
      // Extract alpha
      $alpha = ($col & 0x7F000000) >> 24;
      // Make black with original alpha
      $repl=imagecolorallocatealpha($im,0,0,0,$alpha);
      // Replace in image
      imagesetpixel($im,$x,$y,$repl); 
   }
}
imagePNG($im,"result.png");
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can make all colours go to black using a *threshold* function in ImageMagick like this:

```
<?php
// Load the PNG image 
$im = new Imagick("image.png");

// Make everything black
$im->thresholdimage(65536);
$im->writeImage("result.png");
?>
```

[image]

It would probably be more proper to do it this way though, in case you ever use more than 16-bit per channel quantisation:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -f

<?php
// Load the PNG image 
$im = new Imagick("image.png");

// Work out quantum range - probably 255 or 65535
$m=$im->getQuantumRange();
$m=$m["quantumRangeLong"];

// Make everything darker than that black
$im->thresholdimage($m);
$im->writeImage("result.png");
?>
```